# Is there a defined counting system in Pali?

Tags: pali-language

> ‘‘**Sataṃ sahassānaṃ nirabbudānaṃ,
>
>   Chattiṃsatīṃ pañca ca abbudāni;**
>   Yamariyagarahī nirayaṃ upeti,
>   Vācaṃ manañca paṇidhāya pāpakan’’ti.

~ Cited from: Paṭhamakhatasuttaṃ, Bhaṇḍagāmavagga, Catukkanipātapāḷi, Aṅguttaranikāya, Tipitaka. (English translation: [Paṭhamakaṭasuttaṃ](http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/4Anguttara-Nikaya/Anguttara2/4-catukkanipata/001-bhandagamavaggo-e.html))

> ‘‘Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu vīsatikhāriko kosalako tilavāho. Tato puriso vassasatassa vassasatassa accayena ekamekaṃ tilaṃ uddhareyya; khippataraṃ kho so, bhikkhu, vīsatikhāriko kosalako tilavāho iminā upakkamena parikkhayaṃ pariyādānaṃ gaccheyya, na tveva eko abbudo nirayo. Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati abbudā nirayā, evameko nirabbudanirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati nirabbudā nirayā, evameko ababo nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati ababā nirayā, evameko aṭaṭo nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati aṭaṭā nirayā, evameko ahaho nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati ahahā nirayā, evameko kumudo nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati kumudā nirayā, evameko sogandhiko nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati sogandhikā nirayā, evameko uppalanirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati uppalā nirayā, evameko puṇḍariko nirayo.** Seyyathāpi, bhikkhu, **vīsati puṇḍarikā nirayā, evameko padumo nirayo.** Padume pana, bhikkhu, niraye kokāliko bhikkhu upapanno sāriputtamoggallānesu cittaṃ āghātetvā’’ti.

~ Cited from:  Kokālikasuttaṃ, Brahmasaṃyuttaṃ, Sagāthāvagga, Saṃyuttanikāya, Tipitaka (English translation: [Kokāliko II –– The Bhikkhu Kokālika II](http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/3Samyutta-Nikaya/Samyutta1/06-Brahma-Samyutta/01-Kokalikavaggo-e.html))

According to the above two texts which I have highlighted in bold, it seems there should be a counting system in Pali. Sometimes the lifespan of sentient beings in certain realms used as numbers.

My questions are:

1. Are there any equivalent numbers which can be written in Hindu-Arabic numerals for numbers used in Pali (like **Abbuda, Nirabbuda, Paduma, ...**)?
2. If there is a different counting system in Pali other than I've mentioned, please explain.
3. What is the time period mentioned in **‘‘Sataṃ sahassānaṃ nirabbudānaṃ,
   Chattiṃsatīṃ pañca ca abbudāni"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are there any equivalent numbers which can be written in Hindu-Arabic numerals for numbers used in Pali**

I found one here by Googling for "pali numerals": [Pali Numbers - Ancient Buddhist Texts](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Textual-Studies/Grammar/Pali-Numbers.htm)

> This is a list of commonly found Pāḷi numbers which occur in the literature.

**What is the time period mentioned in ‘‘Sataṃ sahassānaṃ nirabbudānaṃ, Chattiṃsatīṃ pañca ca abbudāni"**

The reference I cited above says,

> 1 + 63 zeros: nirabbutaṁ

[Ven. Sugato's translation](https://suttacentral.net/an4.3/en/sujato) of that sutta says,

> For more than two quinquadecillion years,
>   *Sataṃ sahassānaṃ nirabbudānaṃ,*
>
> and another five quattuordecillion years,
>   *Chattiṃsatī pañca ca abbudāni;*

I don't know if those are the same numbers; I can't count that high in English!